# Can I compare Moran's I z-scores across areas?

Tags: spatial-statistics

I would like to compare the spatial clustering of elderly people (measured as percent of population age>64 in each census tract) across five cities. I have run "Spatial Stat. tools -> Spatial autocorrelation") and obtained a Moran's I z-score for each city. I have applied exactly the same tool parameters for the five cities. My question: does it make sense to compare Moran's I z-scores for the five studied cities? Or can I say that the city with the highest z-score has the greatest level of clustering?